# wikiya toolbar and jquery problem

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I've recently added the [wibiya](http://wibiya.com) toolbar to my site. Since doing that, my jquery script stopped working. I've checked their troubleshooting section and did the trick they are suggesting. Now my jquery works, but I am still getting loads of warning messages and the jquery script act a bit weird...

Has anyone had the same problem? How did you solve it?

Thanks

Comment: can we see some live example? or can you provide some codes?..

Comment: it appears to only work weird in firefox: http://www.aniri.ro/portfolio.php

scroll down in the portfolio list until you reach an image and move the mouse over the image. the images gets bigger as it should, but a weird frame also appears near the bottom of the page.. don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem! I had to disable the "image recognition" option from the smart share app.